# Azure PHP function escapes string output

Tags: php, azure, escaping, azure-functions

I'm playing with Azure PHP functions, and I'm running into a small annoyance, where I can't find any documentation about.

When calling the function, it will take the input, do some transformation on it, and return the result as output of the function. For some reasone however, the output is enclosed in and escaped for quotes.

For instance:
"{\"name\": \"Tom\"}"

Instead of:
{"name": "Tom"}

So the quotes and backslashes are actually part of the HTTP output of the function. The are not added by the actual PHP code of the function. The content type of the response is also always set to application/json, but although I'm returning json, it's double encoded.

Is there a way to prevent that from happening? It doesn't seem right to have to implement some sort of unescaping wherever I need to call this function (eg. from Javascript).

Comment: Are you using Laravel? Also post your code. No one can help you without seeing it.

Comment: What framework? I'm talking about Azure function (aka. serverless). The entire function is litteraly <?php file_put_contents(getenv('res'), '{"name": "Tom"}');

Comment: php for functions was an experimental and is in the process of being removed. I won't recommend using php functions for any thing.

Comment: Sorry @TomCannaerts! I misunderstood, I can't help you out then :(